# Printing a variables with a function stored produces [Function], what does that mean?

Tags: javascript

I am currently reading JavaScript The Definitive Edition to solidify my knowledge and something came uo that I can't quite understand.

I made the example below.

```
//An array of functions returning names.
var nameArray = []
nameArray[0] = function (){return "Bob in nameArray "}
console.log(nameArray[0])   // This will output "[Function]"

console.log(nameArray[0]()) // This will output "Bob in nameArray " as intended
```

Why is it that when I log `nameArray[0]` I get `[Function]`. I understand that the element stored is a function, but ***what does `[Function]` represent***?

Is it the type of the element stored? Is it the actual function object itself? If so, is this the same function object that is created when a function is invoked (where it stores its local variables and outer scope)?

Why is it that I can do the following:

```
// Create object
var nameObject = {
    name:"bob"
}
nameArray[1] = nameObject
console.log(nameArray[1]) // This will print the literal object
```

That will simply print the object.

I guess my questions are: what does `[Function]` actually represents and mean. And if it is an object then why is the object not printed like the nameObject example above considering a function is an object.

Thank you.

Comment: It's just your console's way to show you something is a function. It's not printing it as an object because it's often useless to do so - you *can* add properties to a function but the majority of time, you wouldn't. So, no need to give you the "content", since it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the functions output when you console log them is dependent on the engine. In this case, it just tells you that it's a function. In chrome it'll print out the function as well as indicate that it is a function. [image]

The reason why you can print out a function is because functions are first class entities in JS. Essentially, you can pass them to other functions, assign them to variables and work with them like you might any other object.